# how to highlight AJAX search result in a check box list without losing check box selections in php?

Tags: php, ajax, checkboxlist

I have a check box list of students and a search box in first php page .In ajax page I will get the search results .

But the problem is ,if user selected first search result and searched again selection on the first search is lost

How can I save selections on the first search ?I have tried to make selections in an  session array but it is not working

```
//check list
    $qry="select cand_id,name from candidate where inst_id=".$_SESSION['inst_id']."";
    $res=$ob->select($qry,$connect);
    while($rw=pg_fetch_row($res))
    {

        echo"<br><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[]\" value=\"$rw[0]\">";echo$rw[1];echo"<br>" ;
    }
//Ajax page
if($ajaxData!="")
{
                                if($_SESSION['usertype_id']==1)
                                {
                                $qry="select cand_id,name from candidate where name like'$dataup%'  ";

                                }
                                else if($_SESSION['usertype_id']==2)
                                {
                                $qry="select cand_id,name from candidate where inst_id=".$_SESSION['inst_id']."
                                and  name like'$dataup%' ";
                                }
                                $res=$ob->select($qry,$connect);
                                $words=array();
                                $count = pg_num_rows($res);
                                if($count>0)
                                {
                                    $i=0;
                                    //echo"<div  style=\"width: 200px; height: 200px;overflow-y: auto;padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0.25in;\">";
                                    while($rw=pg_fetch_row($res))
                                    {
                                        $words[$i]=$rw[0];$i++;


                                    }

                                    $_SESSION['checkAjax']=$words;//can_id array
```

1. How do I use array `$_SESSION['checkAjax']` for highlighting?
2. Why `$_SESSION['checkAjax']` unset on each ajax call?
3. Just need change of color on selected student names

Comment: Do you call the [session_start](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function at the beginning of your code to start/resume your session?

Comment: Session start is in  template and i have included it in above page.

Answer (score 1):

I **assume** that you are having a code this way for the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="student"> Student
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="teacher"> Teacher
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="professor"> Professor
```

If this is the case, you can check it on server side this way, and I again **assume** it is by **POST**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="student"<?php echo (in_array("student", $_POST["options"])) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>> Student
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="teacher"<?php echo (in_array("teacher", $_POST["options"])) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>> Teacher
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="professor"<?php echo (in_array("professor", $_POST["options"])) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>> Professor
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help .But in this case there is no form submitting , AJAX is used.

Comment: Thats good. You can use the `.serialize()` function of jQuery right?

Comment: Just include the jQuery Library and use `$.ajax`. Very very simple. Just check out [jQuery's AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).